# How to provide extra information to supervisor when restarting a child in erlang OTP?

Tags: erlang

Say I have a supervisor `sup` supervise some workers, when a worker started, it register itself with some name, like `worker_1`, `worker_2`, etc.. When `worker_N` crashed and get restarted by `sup`, how to register the newly created process as `worker_N`, i.e., how to let the name of a worker survive a restart?

[How to restart child with custom state using Erlang OTP supervisor behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562954/how-to-restart-child-with-custom-state-using-erlang-otp-supervisor-behaviour) gives no answer, since I only want the name, there maybe a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the worker register itself when it is started by having it call `register(Name, self())` in `init` and passing `Name` as an argument there. This is global across the node, so it doesn't matter what process does the registering.

**BUT**

It looks like you are dynamically creating atoms because you want to use registered processes everywhere. This is a *very* common mistake -- but there is hope!

Instead of dynamically creating atoms to name every child worker in existence, consider a few things first:

- You don't need them all named. Workers have a limited job
  description (and if they don't you have bigger problems) and they are
  nearly always tied to their resources, their caller or their spawner,
  who already knows them.
- You do need them named (but really, you probably don't) because they
  represent concrete elements of a large system, like a location in a
  game, a channel in chat, your stalking victim's Twitter feed, etc.
  Name them a different way, by keeping a digest of `[{Key, Value}]`
  where `[{AnyTerm, Pid}]`. This lets you know more about the process by
  looking at its name *and* keeps the global spaces of your system free of
  private worker detritus.

**There's more...**

If you are naming processes integers you are either making the same mistake countless web developers make when using relational databases (making everything have an integer primary key), or you are dealing with workers that *don't need names*.

If you actually do need them named (it happens), consider using the `global` module (it lets you name any process any term you want, and the names are usable across all nodes -- magic!), "process groups" in the `pg2` module, or [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc) (a library written to handle this exact problem, and also lets you use any term you want to name processes).

**A personal note**

If you ever find yourself in a situation where generating dynamic atoms seems like a good idea (for whatever reason) you should *always* stop whatever you are doing and think very hard about what you are doing. This is because generating atoms is a strong indication that *you're doing it wrong*. Try to discover why you are fighting the system so hard -- Erlang isn't meant to work that way.

In every case I've either encountered in my own code or witnessed in the work of others, this sort of thing is a sign that a cleaner, more Erlangy way of doing things exists, and everything just gets easier if I discover whatever that way is instead of adding more layers to the big knot of tangled logic I'm working on. The good news is that accumulating Erlang idioms is quick and they are hard to forget because they usually make *so much sense* in retrospect (nearly always you find you were reinventing the wheel before discovering the accepted solution -- and wind up with a "ah, great minds think alike" feeling at the end).

Comment: This is the best answer I've read on stackoverflow so far. Thanks for these details. I'm using coordinates as names, every worker do the work related with that coordinates, then pass the result to some other workers via `(x, y, z) ! some_msg`, this is why I want to name my workers. This can be described as "1-worker-1-coordinate", if I don't name them, then it should be a "1-worker-many-coordinates", right? In the later case, what's the common pattern for it, should I write a scheduler to tell workers which message should it process?

Comment: I have an identical situation in a teaching project I'm writing (where I evolve a project from naive non-OTP to production OTP style). Initially I keep a registry in the "parent" (its a supervisor, but not a proper one) and respond to `{From, Ref, {get_pid, LocID}}`. `LocID` can be anything, in this case it is `{X,Y,Z}`, but that's incidental. Later I will use `global` (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/global.html) and `global:send(LocID, Msg)` in place of `LocPid ! Msg`, and later on I'll demonstrate pg2 and gproc.

Comment: @NotanID Also, note that over time the "naked" send calls of the form `Destination ! Message` start going away, and get wrapped behind module interface APIs. At the very outset of a project this can be cumbersome, but once you have a solid idea what you're trying to do moving your message calls behind module APIs can be a real lifesaver -- same goes for state data access between modules (don't blindly include record defs in a header!). Here is a (*very* non-OTP) example of the "location manager": https://github.com/zxq9/erlmud/blob/master/erlmud-0.1/locman.erl#L38

Comment: @NotanID Also, don't take the code there as canon. It is deliberately written to be as unidiomatic (but not *wrong*) as possible. Over time that code base will become more Erlangy -- which is the whole point of the demonstration. gproc basically provides this {K,V} type Pid directory service for you, pre-packaged for use. Very cool. Anyway, writing one by hand once is a good way to explore the idea and will make other things about what global, pg2 and gproc do make obvious sense to you later.

Comment: Oh, man, http://zxq9.com/archives/983 and http://zxq9.com/erlmud/html/index.html, exactly what I needed.

Comment: @NotanID Hopefully I will be able to continue working on this so it can be useful to you in a fuller way. I *really* feel this is the subject that is currently missing from the Erlang book collection at the moment. In any case, its not hard to convert hackish Erlang to OTP Erlang incrementally, so be bold in your experiments!

Comment: Agreed. As a noob, I think the language itself is not hard, the difficult part is those design patterns, if I have a problem A, it's well guaranteed I'm not the first one who has this problem, and probably there already is a solution (a pattern) to this problem. For a beginner, it's not easy to find example code in this pattern, after all, there is not a index for this kind of thing, all it relies on is experience. When erlmud is finished, I think it should be placed on the erlang website, learnyousomeerlang for basic stuff, and erlmud for OTP.

Comment: @NotanID As for the Erlang version of "design patterns" I'm making a list as I go along. I want to do a write up on each basic mechanism or technique (large or small) I wind up using in more than one form, and explain the essence of the technique in a way that isolates the core idea from the noisy details of this or that syntax or library. I might re-write an example of each in LFE or Elixir for contrast, just to highlight the difference between essence and artifact. I'd also like to write about non-OTP supervision patterns... Anyway, thanks for your enthusiasm -- its encouraging.